# funcion define con variable

Tags: mysql, pdo, php7

tengo el siguiente código para definir un constante con el valor de una variable:

```
define('DB_NAME', $row['co_database_name']);
```

y usarla en una cadena de conexion

```
$dsn = "mysql:host=" . DB_HOST . ";dbname=" . DB_NAME . ";charset=" . DB_CHARSET . ";port=" . DB_PORT;
$opt = [
   PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
   PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
   PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false,
   PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true,
   ];
$conn = new PDO($dsn, DB_USER, DB_PASS, $opt);
```

pero da error `Undefined variable: conn`

Si lo hago directamente con el nombre de la base de datos... asi:

```
define('DB_NAME', 'nombre_base_datos');
```

Funciona bien, por que? hay otra manera de hacerlo?

Gracias.

Comment: ¿Has verificado si la variable `$row['co_database_name']` existe o te da nulo?

Comment: Si existe y su valor es el nombre de la base de datos.

Comment: ¿Pero has intentado imprimir la variable para ver que sale?

Comment: Si señor, con `var_dump($row['co_database_name'])`

Comment: Creo que el problema esta en `$_SESSION` voy a consultar de nuevo. Gracias